# How to declare buffer in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, buffer

The goal of my program is to pass it an ASCII string of an integer from the command line to the register r0.

I must then convert the ASCII string to a signed integer and return it in r0, this is done in the procedure atoi, and it works perfectly.

I must then initialize a buffer, and call the procedure itoa, with r0 containing the integer and r1 containing the address of the buffer.

The first problem I run into, as there are many I think, is I cannot seem to initialize and declare a buffer, how do I do that?

this is my code so far:
.text
.global _start
.equ exit, 1
.equ write, 4
.equ stdout, 1

```
_start:
    ldr r5, [sp]        @argc value
    ldr r6, =1
    mov r8, #8          @argv address

    ldr r4, [sp, r8]        
    add r8, r8, #4          
    mov r0, r4
    bl atoi
    ldr r1, =buffer 
    bl itoa
    ldr r0, =1
    bl println
    mov r0, #0      @ success exit code
    mov r7, #exit
    svc 0           @ return to os

atoi:
    push {r4, lr}
0:
    ldrb r1, [r0], #1
    cmp r1, #'-
    beq 2f
    cmp r1, #'0
    blo 1f
    cmp r1, #'9
    bhi 1f
    sub r1,r1,#'0
    ldr r3, =0
    mov r3,r2,lsl#3
    add r2,r2,r2
    add r2,r2,r3
    add r2,r2,r1
    bal 0b

1:  cmp r4, #1
    rsbeq r2, r2, #0
    mov r0, r2
    pop {r4, pc}

2:  
    ldr r4, =1
    bal 0b
    
itoa: 
    push {r4, r5, lr}
    mov r4, r1

    
    ldr r5, =0
    push {r5}
    cmp r0,#0
    bgt 4f

    0:  ldr r5, =45
    strb r5, [r4] , #1
    rsb r0, r0, #0

4:  b qr10

3:  add r1, r1, #'0
    push {r1}
    cmp r0, #0
    bne 4b

1:  pop {r5}
    cmp r5, #0
    beq 2f
    strb r5, [r4] , #1
    bal 1b

2:  ldr r1, =buffer 
    pop {r4,r5, pc}
    
    

qr10:
    mov r3, r0      @ save dividend (n)
    ldr r1, =0x1999999a @ 2^32/10
    sub r0, r0, r0, lsr #30 @ adjust for large dividends
    umull r2, r0, r1, r0    @ quotient in r0 (q)
    mov r1, r0, LSL #3  @ 8q
    add r1, r1, r0, LSL #1  @ 10q
    sub r1, r3, r1      @ remainder in r1 (r = n - 10q)
    b 3b



# determine string length
# parameters
#   r0:   address of null-terminated string
# returns
#   r0:   length of string (excluding the null byte)
# modifies r0, r1, r2
strlen:
    @ push {lr}
    mov r1, r0      @ address of string
    mov r0, #0      @ length to return
0:
    ldrb r2, [r1], #1   @ get current char and advance
    cmp r2, #0      @ are we at the end of the string?
    addne r0, #1
    bne 0b
# return
    @ pop  {pc}
    mov pc, lr      @ can do this instead of using the stack

# write a null-terminated string followed by a newline
# parameters
#   r0:  output file descriptor
#   r1:  address of string to print
# modifies r0, r1, r2
println:
    push {r4, r5, r7, lr}
# first get the string length
    mov r4, r0      @ save the fd
    mov r5, r1      @ and the string address
    mov r0, r1      @ the string address
    bl strlen       @ returns the string length in r0
    mov r2, r0      @ put length in r2 for the WRITE syscall
    mov r0, r4      @ restore the fd
    mov r1, r5      @ and the string address
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    mov r0, r4      @ retrieve the fd
    adr r1, CR      @ get the address of the CR string
    mov r2, #1      @ one char to write
    mov r7, #write
    svc 0
    pop {r4, r5, r7, pc}    @ restore registers and return to caller

    CR: .byte '\n
    .data
    buffer:  .space 32
```

Comment: I have edited the code and it does work, except when i try to compare r0 to #0 and branch to 0b if its less than 0. The problem is that it always branches even for the value 132 which is clearly bigger than 0. Any idea why? However when i remove the added code it works flawlessly, the idea behind the added code is to support negative numbers...

Comment: nevermind my previous comment, it was a problem of  placement i have posted the appropriate code and it works! thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: to allocate a buffer in the data segment, use the SPACE directive:

```
buffer: SPACE 16
```

Since SPACE is an assembler directive and not a CPU command, this might be different in your assembler.

To load the address into r1, place an address of the buffer into a register-sized constant in the code segment after the end of the function, and then use LDR to load that:

```
mov pc, lr
p_buffer: dcd buffer
```

Then load where you need it:

```
ldr r1, p_buffer
```

Now r1 contains the contents of p_buffer, which is the address of buffer. Again, the syntax might vary.

Comment: i did not understand, what do you mean when you say subtract the desired buffer size from SP? also can i not use the stack? can i have the address of the buffer in r1 instead? and allocate 16 bytes to my buffer?

Comment: I see you already have a buffer in the `.data` section - is that the one you want to use, and just not sure how to load its address into r1?

Comment: It does not seem to work... its not writing to the buffer, probably because it is not initialized/not enough size....

Comment: Check the value of r1. Can you debug?